# How to open the wifi sign-in page when it doesn't pop up automatically

Tags: macos, network, wifi

One time I was at a hotel and I couldn't access the free wifi because the sign-in window didn't pop up.

Since every webpage has a URL, is it possible to get to the wifi sign-in page through a browser (Google Chrome)?

Knowing how to do this is good for future reference, in case I experience problems connecting to wifi networks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the log in gets eaten by other software or times out, just open your chosen web browser and navigate to ***http://captive.apple.com***

Some interesting tidbits:

- [How captive.apple.com is used by non-Apple devices?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/328370/how-captive-apple-com-is-used-by-non-apple-devices)
- [How to disable captive.apple.com?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/211593/how-to-disable-captive-apple-com)
- [A clear question and answer on implementing a captive portal with key triggers documented for multiple vendors and versions of OS](https://serverfault.com/a/701383/81174)